# Return CSRF in Response

Tags: django-rest-framework, vuejs2, csrf-protection, django-csrf

There is a problem with the return of CSRF. The frontend uses VueJs. 
I have Login API:

```
class UserLoginAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    # @ensure_csrf_cookie
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            new_data = serializer.data
            user = User.objects.get(**new_data)
            context = {
                'username': user.username,
                'id': user.id,
            }
            auth.login(request, user=user)
            log.info("User %s is logged" % data['username'])

            return Response(context)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

As can be seen from the commented line, I tried to write it in a session, but it does not work. I also tried to decorate the URL:

```
path('login/', ensure_csrf_cookie(UserLoginAPIView.as_view()), name="login"),
```

Can you please tell me how to return csrf token to the front-end and check it? Maybe it somehow needs to be returned in Response?